# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.useNavigate) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have been seeing this error from today while creating a new app. I knew there were few changes with the react-router-dom new version and so have installed the older version.

`"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"`

Not sure what is wrong.

Code of the App component

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'


const App = () => {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Header />
          <main className='py-3'>
            <Container>
                <Route path='/' component={LoginScreen} />
            </Container>
          </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
    )
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Please let me know if any other details have to be added.

Answer (score 1):

From the migration guide [upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory), `useNavigate` hook is added for `react-router` v6.

Please check if there is any component that uses this hook. For `react-router` v5, you should use `useHistory()` to get the `history` object and perform the navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. yes I used use navigate.. not sure for what reason history was not working older version as well... Now I updated my routes to the newer one . thanks again